# Touching up Guitar Body

Tags: finishing

I am trying to fix a patch on a guitar, but every time I spray I get this odd fisheye effect:

[image]

I am trying to spray it with Sunburst Black https://www.stewmac.com/Materials_and_Supplies/Finishing_Supplies/ColorTone_Black_Aerosol_Guitar_Lacquer.html

Do I need to use something before this? I am cleaning the surface with naphtha.

Comment: Is that a particularly bad case of fish-eye? If it is very thorough cleaning can prevent this but it can be amazingly persistent so doesn't always work. In those cases there are a couple of fixes but with a spraycan lacquer I think the go-to would be to seal the surface off with shellac. You have fresh lacquer on there now and I think it's necessary to remove all of this and start from scratch, doing so may clean the surface sufficiently well. But you'll have to try it and see. Probably best to expect that you will need to apply a shellac barrier coat so it doesn't come as a surprise.

Comment: It's not a defect; it's a feature!